# How does 设A是..., 若A的..., 则称A是... work for mathematical definitions?

Tags: grammar

From a Baidu page about [拉丁矩](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%8B%89%E4%B8%81%E7%9F%A9) (Latin rectangles, a topic in combinatorial mathematics, and one of my research topics), we have the following sentence (listed as 定义1; I trim back some of the mathematics notation):

> **设A是**一个m×s矩阵，**若A的**任一行是集{1,...,n}的一个s-排列，任一列是集{1,...,n}的一个m-排列，**则称A是**一个m×s拉丁矩。

I translate this to something like:

> If A is an m×s matrix, such that every row is an s-permutation of {1,...,n} and every column is an m-permutation of {1,...,n}, then A is a Latin rectangle.

I'm confused about the grammar here, and in particular, the use of (what seems to be) the following:

> 设A是[a mathematical object], 若A的[conditions], 则称A是[a special type of that mathematical object].

I'm seeking a better overall idea of how this structure works, e.g., how frequently this is used, other examples, and what [设](http://dict.cn/%E8%AE%BE), [若](http://dict.cn/%E8%8B%A5), [则](http://dict.cn/%E8%8B%A5) and [称](http://dict.cn/%E7%A7%B0) are doing in the sentence.

**Question**: How does 设A是..., 若A的..., 则称A是... work for mathematical definitions?

Comment: see dictionaries, 设suppose, 若if, supposing, assuming, 则 then, 称 (call, name)is called, for more examples, find English original and Chinese translation of mathematical textbooks (available at university libraries)

Comment: But I think there's more materials in English about Latin Squares hahaha. P.S. I was taught the term "Latin Square" 拉丁方 when I was learning discrete mathematics last year. : )

Comment: 则称是 is a little weird. I think it should be 则称A是. Then (we) call A [a special type of that mathematical object]. What's important is , I can't find your original sentence in the link, is it edited by anyoneone after you post this question?

Comment: Oh I see the difference: A latin square has to be a square while a latin rectangle doesn't.

Comment: @神秘德里克 Yeah, I find that the original sentence in the given link is actually “则称A是”.

Comment: 任一行是 "every row"? Are you sure it's not "any row"? After all, original sentence you post is not 任一行都是. How do you define this concept based on your own math knowledge?

Comment: There's some copy/paste errors with the mathematics; I hope I fixed them now.  (It's "every row" and "every column" mathematically; "any row" and "any column" would be incorrect.)

Comment: If it meant to be "every row", then I think 任一行是 is a little ambiguous. Maybe you should say 任一行都是. Then you can see user6065's comment, these words are actually used straight forward. It's very typical to talk about things using such formal words in Math context, not daily conversation.

Comment: Mathematics and daily conversation are not so separate for me (:.  Also, I'm preparing to give my first (mathematics) presentation in Chinese, at [a conference](http://ahuweb.ahu.cn/math/index.asp) in August, which I hope won't be a total disaster.

Comment: @Becky李蓓 WOW, I find one of the lecturers a professor of my university!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- 「設」is short for [假設](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%81%87%E8%A8%AD#Chinese) (**Suppose that...**)
- 「若」means **if**
- 「則稱」, literally **then (it is) called**, should just be taken as **then**.

> 設A是一個m×s矩陣，若A的任一行是集{1,...,n}的一個s-排列，任一列是集{1,...,n}的一個m-排列，則稱A是一個m×s拉丁矩。
>
> 「Suppose that」***A*** is an *m* by *s* matrix.「If」every row of ***A*** is an *s*-permutation of {1, ..., *n*} and every column is an *m*-permutation of {1, ..., *n*},「then」***A*** is an *m* by *s* Latin rectangle.